# How to bind combobox Category item to it's categoryId

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a combobox, which holds Categories objects.

```
<ComboBox Name="cbxCategory" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" SelectedValue="{Binding Category, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource RegularControlStyles}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding CategoryName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

and I have the DataContext which is:

```cs
public class EventFilter
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int? Duration { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

All the fields are bound well except the two comboboxes (Category and SubCategory).

The problem is that the combobox holds a Category object and the EventFilter holds the id of it. One solution I can do is just to change the property:

```cs
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
```

to:

```cs
public int Category { get; set; }
```

But I don't want to do that, I want to hold the id.
So How can I do it?

Should I use a converter?
If I change in the binding of the combobox to:

```cs
SelectedValue="{Binding CategoryId, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

It's not working as well because it holds Categories.

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `SelectedValuePath` property of the `ComboBox` to the name of your property... in this case, I'm guessing that you have a property named 'Id' on your `Category` class. Then, the `SelectedValue` property will provide the value of the 'Id' property from the selected `Category` object.

You can find out more from the [Selector.SelectedValuePath Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx) page at MSDN.

You may want or need to also set the `DisplayMemberPath` property... this defines which property of the selected `Category` object will be displayed in the control.

You can find out more from the [ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) page at MSDN.

```
<ComboBox Name="cbxCategory" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" 
    SelectedValuePath="CategoryId" SelectedValue="{Binding EventFilterItems.CategoryId}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" Style="{StaticResource RegularControlStyles}" />
```

Note that you will need to bind the `SelectedValue` property of the `ComboBox` to the `CategoryId` property of the current `EventFilter` object.